Switcher action does not work any more in PhpStorm
I had the Switcher action in PHPStorm, but it doesn't work anymore.
I have this setting Ctrl+Tab:

I have also verified my Tab key mapping as shown in Tab and Enter key do not work any more in the WebStorm editor while typing
It works with other key combinations, like Ctrl+Shift++.


There is a button on that Keymap screen -- next to the local search field (will be top right, above that on your screenshot). It allows you to press a shortcut and it will show all actions that have that shortcut assigned. Show what it shows for you (what actions). 2) Is this local development, or a remote?


Yes I tried the button, and when trying Crtl + Tab, it finds the swicther action associated to this key combo. Well it may come from elsewhere, maybe a plugin.

Disable all custom (not bundled by default) plugins, restart the IDE and try again -- any difference?


What IDE version are you currently using? 4) New UI or the old/standard one? 5) What OS? 6) Do you have "Screen readers" option enabled? If yes -- will it do better if you disable it? 7) What keyboard layout you have (QWERTY/Dvorak etc) 8) Anything interesting in the idea.log when that happens?


Other than that -- go trough comments in the following ticket, seems related: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IJPL-119598

Good catch! It's OK when deactivating the "Support screen reader option". Thanks.

As indicated by @Lazyone, the answer was in this similar issue on the Jetbrains youtrack.
I have deactivated the "Support Screen readers" option in the "Appearance" parameters section and now it back to normal:

